# WCF service not opening in the browser?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm learning WCF, I started creating a very basic host app which defines a class with one method as follows:

```
 [ServiceContract()]
    public interface IMath
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Add(int a, int b);
    }
    public class MathCalcs : IMath
    {
        public MathCalcs()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service await two numbers...");
        }
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
```

and that is how I configured the App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleHost.MathCalcs" behaviorConfiguration="MathServiceMEXBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/MathCalcs"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="ConsoleHost.IMath"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/MathCalcs"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MathServiceMEXBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Then I called the service from `Main`

```
 using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MathCalcs)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("***The service is ready***");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

But it fails to view the metadata of the service through the URI http://localhost:8080/MathCalcs, I'm sure I'm following the steps right as the book I'm reading from and as a preceding example works fine, the only difference is that I didn't separate the service logic (the interface and the class) in a stand alone class library. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following  line of code

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

must be inside the braces of the using clause!
When that is done, retry finding the WSDL metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related post that I think may lead you in the right direction.

[WCF service showing blank in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764574/wcf-service-showing-blank-in-browser)